# ERROR: NoConfigFoundException Check that your config file `flutter_launcher_icons.yaml` has a `flutter_icons` section

Tags: flutter

Description of problem: I am trying to add the launcher icon in the `pubspec.yaml` file but it is showing me this error.
I have tried to even add assets too in the flutter but still not working. When I run `flutter pub get` no error is shown.
Then I run the command as mentioned in the `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` getting above error.

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  retrofit: any
  json_annotation: ^3.1.1
  provider: ^4.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  http: ^0.12.1
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  dio: ^3.0.10


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  retrofit_generator : any
  json_serializable: ^3.5.1
  build_runner: any
  flutter_launcher_icons: any

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
    # optionally, as transparency is not allowed on app store
    # remove_alpha_ios: true
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icons/ic_launcher_square.png"
# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the wrong indentation as I was facing the same problem but now it worked for me

```yaml
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"

flutter_icons:
 android: true
 ios: true
 image_path: "assets/images/cloudy.png"
```

take care of the spacing behind the lines you are writing

or take a look here

[image: Screenshot]